# Why is the circle $S^1$ semi-locally simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am working from the definition in [these notes](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/II_M/algebraic_topology.pdf#page=33), but they seem to agree with other things I read:

> $X$ is semi-locally simply connected if for all $x_0 \in X$, there is some neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that any loop $\gamma$ based at $x_0$ is homotopic to $c_{x_0}$ as paths in $X$.

(edit: this should specify that $\gamma \subset U$)

I'm not sure why $S^1$ meets this defition, since any nonconstant loop must wind the circle completely and is never going to be contractible. The only thing I can think of is: for any $x_0 \in S^1$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ where the only possible loop you can draw is the constant loop. So trivially this is homotopic to the constant loop. Is that the correct interpretation?

Thank you!

Comment: The notation $\gamma \in U$ means that $\gamma$ is a **point in $U$**. You mean that the image of the loop $\gamma$ is a subset of $U$.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant $\subset$, have changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct interpretation, because it is not true that "any nonconstant loop must wind the circle completely". A loop can go back and forth over a small neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Ah! That was my misunderstanding - very silly of me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the notes is incomplete: it should specify that the loop $\gamma$ is supposed to be in $U$. Then, the complete definition reads that the neighbourhood $U$ must be such that all loops in it are homotopic as paths in the larger space $X$ to the constant path (though not necessarily as paths in the neighbourhood). Namely, a homotopy between $\gamma$ and $c_{x_0}$ may partially range outside $U$, although this isn't the case for $S^1$ because it's locally simply connected.

Comment: Thank you, you are right about $\gamma \in U$, I but this is not quite my question. A fully winding loop in $S^1$ is not contractible in $S^1$. So is my hypothesis (that the only loops in $U$ are the constant loops) the correct reason?